# Error attempting to update a SQL Database from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am attempting to update a SQL database from SharePoint.  I have no problem making the connection and SELECTING data.  However, no matter what I do I get the following error when attempting to update:

The data source control failed to execute the update command. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

I have tried removing the PK so it doesnt' attempt to change it but still no luck.  I think it may have something to do with the columns in SQL being numeric or datetime and SharePoint, bringing it into the page and converting it, by design, to text. Then when I repost it doesn't know how to convert back.  Not sure if this is accurate.  I just need some answers quick.  Got a deadline.  All I am trying to do is update two fields one with a Y/N flag and another with a time stamp for when the flag is set.

Help;-)

Comment: Is this a dataview web part you're working with or what?